# Как можно узнать что в таблицу базы SQLite была добавлена запись, не обращаясь SELECT'ом к таблице. С/С++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c, sqlite

В БД есть таблица, в которую другим приложением добавляются строки. Как узнать что в таблицу была добавлена новая строка не обращаясь к таблице SELECT'ом. Дело в том, что данная информация должна получаться практически мгновенно. Дергать БД запросами каждые 200мс не хочется. Есть ли возможность использовать флаги дескриптора файла БД или еще как-то? Программа на С++ под Linux.

Попробовал вариант со stat(), он позволяет отследить время последнего изменения файла БД, тем самым количество ненужных запросов можно сократить, но это как-то криво...

По совету @KoVadim попробовал sqlite3_update_hook(), но этот хук ловит изменения в таблице при использовании соединения объекта БД, который производит изменения. В моем случае изменения вносит другая прога, у которой открыто свое соединение.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html

Comment: Похоже то, что надо. Спасибо!

Comment: Идея была хорошая, но... не получилось. sqlite3_update_hook() ловит изменения в таблице при использовании соединения объекта БД, который производит изменения. В моем случае изменения вносит другая прога, у которой открыто свое соединение.

Comment: я подозревал это.

Comment: Может быть стоит возложить на прогу, которая меняет вашу таблицу еще и инициирование действий, которые вы хотите производить при изменении этой таблицы?

Comment: Да, вероятнее всего, так и придется делать. Какой-нибудь маяк через сокет или фифо.

Answer (score 0):

В sqlite нет ни publish/subsribe, ни notify, ни очередей. Для взаимодействия с другим процессом нужно создавать внешний механизм, а sqlite использовать только для хранения таблиц.

Единственное что можно сделать внутри базы - это создать таблицу log в которую  триггером заносятся нужные изменения, а второй процесс будет эту таблицу перечитывать и учтенные изменения удалять. Перечитка остается, но объем данных будет меньше.

Comment: Для сокращения объема БД и обеспечения необходимой надежности работы приложения это у меня и реализовано: и триггеры, и дополнительные таблицы... Но Логгер событий это одна прога, а обработчик событий - другая. Еще есть мысли сделать вторую базу из нужных табличек и троллить ее, а при появлении новых строк открывать (или держать постоянно открытым) соединение с основной БД и от туда по айдишникам забирать нужные данные. Но тут обнаруживается проблема с внешними ключами...